# Understanding bit manipulation (set/clear) in C programming

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

I'm stuck understanding bit operations on integers in C.

Suppose I have the number 13.  Its binary representation is `1101`.  How can I set the bit at its second position?  How can I clear the bit?

Here is the function I wrote so far for setting the bit:

```
int setBit(int data, int pos, int val)
{       
    if (val==1)
        data |= (1U << (pos - 1));
    else
        data ^= (1U << (pos-1));

    return data;
}
```

Will this work correctly?

Comment: xor `^` is used to *toggle* the bit, not clear. And even after fixing that, your program still works incorrectly for val = 2 or anything nonzero and not 1, which is also considered `true`

Comment: Can you please be more precise: *add extra bit at second position* and *remove at specific position* are confusing expressions.  Do you want to **set** the `0` bit in `1101`, and later **clear** or **reset** a bit given its position numbered from the least significant one?

Comment: I dont understand the negative votes on this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting, clearing and toggling the state of a bit is straightforward:

```
inline void bit_set (unsigned long *bf, unsigned char n) 
{ *bf |= (1 << n); }

inline void bit_clear (unsigned long *bf, unsigned char n) 
{ *bf &= ~(1 << n); }

inline void bit_toggle (unsigned long *bf, unsigned char n) 
{ *bf ^= (1 << n); }
```

**Note:** bitfields, and the functions above, are **zero based** (i.e. the least significant bit is `bit 0` not `bit 1`) So if you want to clear, set or toggle the second bit from the right (`bit index 1`, the `2's bit (binary)`, or `bit 2` counting right-to-left), you pass a `bit index of 1`. `n` in the functions above is the `bit index`. The following is a quick reference:

```
           +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
bit index  |  7  |  6  |  5  |  4  |  3  |  2  |  1  |  0  |
           +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
binary     | 128 |  64 |  32 |  16 |   8 |   4 |   2 |   1 |
           +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Here is a quick example of the use operating on `bit 1`, (the 2's bit in binary):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define WDSZ 64

/* bit functions */
inline void bit_set     (unsigned long *bf, unsigned char n) { *bf |= (1 << n); }
inline void bit_clear   (unsigned long *bf, unsigned char n) { *bf &= ~(1 << n); }
inline void bit_toggle  (unsigned long *bf, unsigned char n) { *bf ^= (1 << n); }

/* simple return of binary string */
char *binstr (unsigned long n);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    unsigned long bf = (argc > 1) ? strtoul (argv[1], NULL, 10) : 13;

    printf ("\n original value  : %3lu  (%s)\n", bf, binstr (bf));

    bit_set (&bf, 1);
    printf (" set bit 1       : %3lu  (%s)\n", bf, binstr (bf));

    bit_clear (&bf, 1);
    printf (" clear bit 1     : %3lu  (%s)\n", bf, binstr (bf));

    bit_toggle (&bf, 1);
    printf (" toggle bit 1    : %3lu  (%s)\n\n", bf, binstr (bf));

    return 0;
}

/* simple return of binary string */
char *binstr (unsigned long n) {

    static char s[WDSZ + 1] = {0};
    char *p = s + WDSZ;

    while (n) {
        p--;
        *p = (n & 1) ? '1' : '0';
        n >>= 1;
    }
    return p;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/bitsetcleartoggle

 original value  :  13  (1101)
 set bit 1       :  15  (1111)
 clear bit 1     :  13  (1101)
 toggle bit 1    :  15  (1111)
```

Comment: Your example is a tad confusing: you print `bit 2` but modify bit `1`.   It is unusual to name the bits by the power of 2 they represent: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16...

Comment: Yes, the bitfields are **0 based** (i.e. 0-7 for char) while the question was referring to the bits as **1 based** (i.e. 1-8 for char). That's why I dropped a comment in the example `0 based index, e.g. bit 0-63`. The purpose of the example was to illustrate the whole point. While attempting to avoid confusion, I see how it could have contributed to it.

Answer (score 2):

`n = n & (~(1U <<x))` will reset the bit in position x.
Actually what we are doing suppose n=1101
We want to reset 3rd bit.

### How does it work?

So 1U <<3=000....1000

~( 1U <<3)=111....0111

n=000..1101

& 111..0111

Result is  000..0101.

### For inserting a bit y at position  x:(position starts from 0)

1101---->11y01
Giving the example for position 2.

```
num= FFFF FFFF (in hex)(all 1's) //1111......1111
number=N  // in which you will insert bit
num1=num<<x;      //for x=2 as in this case
                  //num1=1111.....1100
num2=~(num1);     //num2=0000.....0011
lowbits=N & num2; //    =0000.....0001 (N=1101)
highbits= N &num1;//    =0000.....1100
highbits<<=1;     //    =0000....11000 
N= highbits | lowbits;//=0000....11001
```

Now set the x-th bit(here x=2) as you required using the method described below

---

**Note**: More generally changing the kth bit of number n to y (maybe 0 or 1) can be done this way

```
n^=(-y ^ n) & (1U <<k); (&- logical and)
```

Deletion of a bit is similar to insertion. Step by step perform the operation and you will get it.

**EDIT**: I have changed the use of 1 to 1U because in first case when using only 1 without any modifiers is defined to be an signed int. From K&R the right shifts of signed values are implementation defined. Also if you left-shift a signed number so that the sign bit is affected, the result is undefined.

> These operations on unsigned value have well define behaviour: Vacated fields are filled with zeroes.

Comment: but i want to insert bit in at third position so output like 11011

Comment: for inserting i need insert code setBit code i have and it work fine but inserting is not possible with this..i hope You understand what i try to do

Comment: so how can i perform insertion

Comment: sorry  typo mistake done there i update it ya i want like this

Comment: Now You got it what i want

Comment: @uzaif.: Check the answer now. Hope it will help.

Comment: @amalsom: `n=n^(-y ^ n) && (1<<k);` will set n to `0` or `1`.  If `y` is `0` or `1`, it simplifies to `n=y;`.  Probably not what you intended.

Comment: #chqrlie i dont understand Your code man can You please Explain in detail

Comment: @chqrlie.: I have missed a parenthesis. I have corrected it. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @chqrlie.: Okay! modifying the answer.

Comment: k is for position and y is for bit

Comment: It is not my code, it is amalsom's.  `&&` is a logical operator, not a bitwise operator. According to precedence rules, this expression is evaluated as `n = (n ^ ((-y) ^ n)) && (1 << k);`.  If `k` is less than the number of bits in an `int`, we get `(n ^ ((-y) ^ n))`.  `^` is commutative and associative, hence: `((n ^ n) ^ (-y))`.  `(n ^ n)` is `0`, and `0 ^ (-y)` is `-y`.  `-y && 1` is `0` if and only if `y == 0`. If `y` is `0` or `1`, we get `n = y;` QED.

Comment: @amalsom: still using the wrong operator `&&`.  You should use `&`.  You should also use `1U` instead of `1` to avoid a potential `int` arithmetic overflow.  Lastly, this code does not work if `n` has a larger type than `unsigned int` and `k` is equal or larger than the number of bits in an `int`.

Comment: @uzaif.: If answer was useful atleast upvote or accept it. That is what makes the post useful to future users.

Comment: @amalsom: This version should work.  Your comment on right shifting signed integers is informative but does not apply here.  Using `(uintmax_t)1` is clever but will trigger a warning on some compilers because of the potential loss of precision when storing the `uintmax_t` expression to `n`.  An alternative such as `((n & 0) + 1U)` has the type of `n` (or `unsigned int` if larger), but relies on the optimizer and is less readable and still misses the `unsigned` requirements if `n` is `long int`.  There might be a better solution.

Comment: @chqrlie.: Should I use 1U instead?

Comment: @amalsom: In the present case, `n` is an `int`, so `1U` is the preferred solution.  In the general case where we are looking for an expression for all types, `(uintmax_t)1` is a clever solution.  I posted a simpler response for the OP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73508/discussion-between-amalsom-and-chqrlie).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple answer for what I understand your problem to be:

```
int setBit(int data, int pos, int val) {
    if (val)
        return data | (1U << (pos - 1));
    else
        return data & ~(1U << (pos - 1));
}
```

But I think numbering the bits starting at `1` is not a good idea. The more common usage is to number the bits from `0` to `sizeof(type) * CHAR_BIT - 1`

Answer (score 0):

whenever I have a problem like this I will break it down into smaller parts...

> suppose i have no 13 binary of 13 is 1101
>
> now how can i add extra bit at second position?

ok that is pretty straight forward... first let make a number with a bit in the second position, zero's everywhere else... we will use an int for convenience...

```
int mask = 2; // or 0x2 if you rather or 0b10 if your compiler supports that ...
```

well that isn't very special, I can't reuse that machinery as it were... so let try a different way...

```
int mask = 1 << 1; // 1 in the fist position moved one to the left...
```

ok now we have part, now there are 2 intuitive ways to set that on our 13...

```
int answer = 13 | mask; // binary OR
```

or

```
int answer = 13 + mask;
```

these 2 are the same for 13... but will give you different answers for 14... because `+` always adds the value, and `|` will only change the bits that aren't set on the left side... so you need to pick the semantics that are correct for you...

now your second question is a little trickier ... first we will pick the same mask...

```
//pick nth bit
int mask = 1 < n;
// now to toggle that on a number... XOR
int answer = q ^ mask;
```

I like using the n'th vs position because it makes more sense in the 0 case...

Answer (score 0):

```
    //For Inserting Bit 

    int insertbit(int data,int pos,int val)
{
    int no1,no2;

    no1=data;

    no1=no1>>(pos-1);

    no1=no1<<(pos-1);

    no2=data-no1;

    no1=no1<<1;

    no1=no1 | no2;

        if(val==1)
      {
           no1=setbit(no1,pos,val);
      }

    return no1;
}

          //Setting Bits



    int setbit(int data,int pos,int val)
{
            int no=1;

           no=no<<(pos-1);

            if(val==0)
        {
            no=~no;
            data=data&no;
        }   
            else
        {
            data=no|data;
        }


        return data;

}
```

I Coded This Way But I Need Some Shortcut for code insert function